# Django REST - How to get an object with connected user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a route in Django REST Framework so that I can access a comment from the object it is related to.

My models are `Comment`, `User` and `Marker`, and each marker can have one comment per user.

What I would like is a way to do `GET /comments/marker/{marker-pk}/` that would return the comment that the connected user left on that marker, if any.

Right now I have `GET /comments/{comment-pk}/` which is the default, and if I use a `@detail_route` decorator on a custom method I'll only have access to comments but not by marker.

My viewset:

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarkerCommentSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to do this while I was writing the question. Not sure if it is very idiomatic or RESTful though...

I added a new route:

```
router.register(r'comments/marker', maps_views.CommentByMarkerViewSet, base_name="comments/marker")
```

And a new `ViewSet`:

```
class CommentByMarkerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, user=request.user, marker__pk=pk)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(comment)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now I can access the comment at `/comments/marker/{marker-pk}/`.

Comment: Hi! I guess you are on the right way. The only minor comment is that if marker is a 'container' for comments, then the normal practice is to access comments via /markers/{marker_pk}/comments. This can be easily done using nested routing. For that checkout package drf-nested-routers. On Github they have a very easy to catch example: https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers/